# Check if binary tree is searchable

Tags: swift, binary-tree

I know this has a ton of answers on here but I couldn't find one with Swift 3+ to check against what I wrote. I knew I was going to run into a problem with force unwrapping the child nodes  - see code below:

```
func isBST(_ node:Tree) -> Bool  {
    return validNode(node:node, minValue:INT8_MIN, maxValue:INT8_MAX)

}

func validNode(node: Tree, minValue:Int32, maxValue:Int32) -> Bool {

    return node.value > minValue && node.value < maxValue && validNode(node:node.leftChild!, minValue: minValue, maxValue: Int32(node.value)) && validNode(node:node.rightChild!, minValue: Int32(node.value), maxValue: maxValue)

}
```

Eventually I will hit a leaf and the nodes will be nil. But (and I am teaching myself Swift so bear with me) I am not sure how to work around this. Do I put in nil coalescing for the node - node: node.leftChild ?? nil? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
func validNode(node: Tree?, minValue:Int32, maxValue:Int32) -> Bool {
    guard let node = node else { return true }
    return node.value > minValue
        && node.value < maxValue 
        && validNode(node:node.leftChild, minValue: minValue, maxValue: Int32(node.value)) 
        && validNode(node:node.rightChild, minValue: Int32(node.value), maxValue: maxValue)
}
```

This allows the validNode() function to accept nil values for node and when it receives a nil value you have hit a leaf node so returns true.

Comment: Surely you want to return false if the node is nil?

Comment: Then validNode() would always return false. You would eventually reach a leaf node and the returned false would propagate up.

Comment: That cleared it up. I wasn't making the passed node optional so my guard or if let statements were not being accepted. Thanks!